# Might do it later when

Tags: meaning

I MIGHT do it later when we are more developed as a team.

is "more developed" one point in time, or a long state in time? Does it mean as soon as they get more developed, he might do it? Or sometime after? I'm confused.

how do we know when something is "more developed"?

Comment: “When we are more developed as a team” is non-commital.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "more developed" is in the eye of the beholder. It might be a point in time when some specific milestones are reached, but it also might be a longer state in time, after which the team can say from themselves that they are more developed. As for "I might do it later", for me, "might" implies that the person won't do it for sure, but will maybe do it when their team is more developed. "Later" is to indicate that it will be in the future.

Comment: Well, in my clan there are levels, higher the better, so if someone who is a high level joins, would you say you are "more developed"? What does "more developed" mean?

Comment: I wondered about this too, that's why I wrote that "more developed is in the eye of the beholder". Someone with a high school diploma might find someone with a bachelor's degree impressive, but someone with a Ph.D. might find the person with the bachelor's degree to have very little knowledge if that makes sense.